# ClassCastException in Java in the HierarchyStruc class as follows

Tags: java, java-8

I am getting ClassCastException in Java but unable to resolve. Could someone tell me what am I missing here?

Here is my class:

```
private List<Record> getGenericRecordsforHierarchy(int hID, Schema schema,List<HierarchyStruc> hs, int maxLevel) throws BookHierarchyException {        
        List<GenericData.Record> recordList = new ArrayList<GenericData.Record>();
        GenericData.Record record = new GenericData.Record(schema);
        for (int i = 0; i < hs.size(); i++) {
            record = new GenericData.Record(schema);
            record.put("HierarchyId", hID);
            for (int j = 0; j <= (maxLevel*3) && j < ((Constants.MAX_ALLOWED)*3); j++) {
                int k=0;
                record.put("Level" + (k+1) + "Id", hs.get(j));
                record.put("Level" + (k+1) + "Desc", hs.get(j+1) );
                record.put("Level" + (k+1) + "nodeId", hs.get(j+2) );
                j= j+2;
                k++;
                if (j + 1 > (maxLevel*3) || null == hs.get(j+1)) {                  
                    record.put("parentNodeId", hs.get(i).getParentNodeId());
                    record.put("BookName", hs.get(i).getBookName());
                    record.put("HierarchyName", hs.get(i).getHierarchyName());
                    record.put("NodeDesc", hs.get(i).getNodeDesc());
                    break;
                }
            }
            recordList.add(record);
        }
        return recordList;
    }
```

My Generic.Record class is as follows:

```
public static class Record implements GenericRecord, Comparable<Record> {
    private final Schema schema;
    private final Object[] values;
    public Record(Schema schema) {
      if (schema == null || !Type.RECORD.equals(schema.getType()))
        throw new AvroRuntimeException("Not a record schema: "+schema);
      this.schema = schema;
      this.values = new Object[schema.getFields().size()];
    }
    public Record(Record other, boolean deepCopy) {
      schema = other.schema;
      values = new Object[schema.getFields().size()];
      if (deepCopy) {
        for (int ii = 0; ii < values.length; ii++) {
          values[ii] = INSTANCE.deepCopy(
              schema.getFields().get(ii).schema(), other.values[ii]);
        }
      }
      else {
        System.arraycopy(other.values, 0, values, 0, other.values.length);
      }
    }
    @Override public Schema getSchema() { return schema; }
    @Override public void put(String key, Object value) {
      Schema.Field field = schema.getField(key);
      if (field == null)
        throw new AvroRuntimeException("Not a valid schema field: "+key);

      values[field.pos()] = value;
    }
    @Override public void put(int i, Object v) { values[i] = v; }
    @Override public Object get(String key) {
      Field field = schema.getField(key);
      if (field == null) return null;
      return values[field.pos()];
    }
    @Override public Object get(int i) { return values[i]; }
    @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (o == this) return true;                 // identical object
      if (!(o instanceof Record)) return false;   // not a record
      Record that = (Record)o;
      if (!this.schema.equals(that.schema))
        return false;                             // not the same schema
      return GenericData.get().compare(this, that, schema, true) == 0;
    }
    @Override public int hashCode() {
      return GenericData.get().hashCode(this, schema);
    }
    @Override public int compareTo(Record that) {
      return GenericData.get().compare(this, that, schema);
    }
    @Override public String toString() {
      return GenericData.get().toString(this);
    }
  }
```

Getting error in below method:

```
private void writeToParquet(String hadoopPath, List<Record> recordList, Schema schema)
            throws BookHierarchyException {
        org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path path = new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(hadoopPath);
        ParquetWriter<GenericData.Record> writer = null;

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration(false);
        configuration.set("fs.file.impl", org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());

        try {
            writer = AvroParquetWriter.<GenericData.Record>builder(path)
                    .withRowGroupSize(ParquetWriter.DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE).withPageSize(ParquetWriter.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE)
                    .withSchema(schema).withConf(new Configuration()).withCompressionCodec(CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY)
                    .withValidation(false).withDictionaryEncoding(false).build();

            for (GenericData.Record record : recordList) {
                writer.write(record);
            }
            log.info("File writing done. Closing file");
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(e);
            throw new BookHierarchyException("Error in file handling");
        }
    }
```

Error is :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: HierarchyStruc cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
```

Could someone please let me know what am I doing wrong here? I matched the schema type and the column types of HierarchyStruc but they are also matching. This seems to be a different issue which I am trying to resolve since morning.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.package.beans.HierarchyStruc cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
        at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroWriteSupport.fromAvroString(AvroWriteSupport.java:371)
        at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroWriteSupport.writeValueWithoutConversion(AvroWriteSupport.java:346)
        at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroWriteSupport.writeValue(AvroWriteSupport.java:278)
        at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroWriteSupport.writeRecordFields(AvroWriteSupport.java:191)
        at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroWriteSupport.write(AvroWriteSupport.java:165)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.write(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:128)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter.write(ParquetWriter.java:299)
        at com.package.utilities.ParquetFileHandler.writeToParquet(ParquetFileHandler.java:73)



        public void persistHierarchyData(String dateYYYY_MM_DD, int hID, List<HierachyStruc> hs, int maxLevel) 
            throws BookHierarchyException {
        Schema schema = parquetSchemaParser.parseSchema(avroSchemaName);
        String hadoopPath = getUpdatedDatePattern(hadoopDirectory + hadoopFileName,dateYYYY_MM_DD);
        hadoopPath = getUpdatedHierarchyPattern(hadoopPath, hID);
        List<GenericData.Record> recordList = getGenericRecordsforHierarchy(hID, schema, hs,maxLevel);
        log.info("recordList size is " + recordList.size());
        parquetFileHandler.persist(schema, recordList, hadoopPath);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to tell from your code because it's incomplete. You have provided a function, `getGenericRecordsforHierarchy`, but it's not called anywhere. You haven't provided the stack trace for the `ClassCastException` so we don't even know where it's occurring.

That said, this is suspicious:

```
record.put("Level" + (k+1) + "Id", hs.get(j));
record.put("Level" + (k+1) + "Desc", hs.get(j+1) );
record.put("Level" + (k+1) + "nodeId", hs.get(j+2) );
```

Here you're adding entire `HierarchyStruc` instances to a `GenericData.Record`, but the keys suggest that they should be strings. If you pass the `Record` to something that expects the fields to be strings, then it will throw the exception you're seeing.

If you could provide the stack trace and the source code for the classes that appear int the trace (if available) then I could give you a better answer.

Comment: @willisbackburn

Comment: What does your `Schema` say the type of the field `Level1Id` is?

Comment: it is long and other two are string

Comment: level1id is long and desc and src I'd are string

Comment: Right. But look at the code I quoted in my answer. You're storing `hs.get(j+1)` into `Level1Desc,` but `hs` is a `List<HierarchyStruc>` and so `hs.get(j+1)` must be `HierarchyStruc`, not a string.

Comment: So will Long.valueOf(hs.get(j+1)) work? If not, what is the solution?

Comment: You probably want something like `record.put("Level" + (k+1) + "Desc", hs.get(j+1).getNodeDesc())`.